# Can I use "that" instead of "who"?

Tags: word-choice

> You can never stop people **who** are wiling to die

May I use "that" instead of "who"?

Answer (score 2):

I have read and confirmed it in many places - both are okay though some believe that *who-goes-with-people* rule is still better. Nevertheless, *that* is a relative pronoun there so it'll also work.

Well, my **personal choice** is *who* as *that* (though serving as a relative pronoun) does not look used for a *human/living thing* as compared to *who*

Further reading [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-that)

Comment: Your reference says: It is "entirely" acceptable to write either the man that wanted to talk to you, or the man who wanted to talk to you - See more at: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-that#sthash.YuMAHLuL.dpuf

Comment: I already said **both are okay** in my very first sentence! I then talked about my personal opinion. And the link is for **further reading**.

Comment: I don't think this is as hotly divisive as the article implies. They are interchangeable and most English speakers will not notice. That said, you frequently see "who" as a relative pronoun in hyperbole than in everyday speech.

Comment: This aligns with my view on the subject. In writing, I often find myself changing _that_ to _who_ in my second draft, simply because it sounds a little better. In speech, sometimes _that_ will come out of my mouth, and it still passes as acceptable speech.

Answer (score 2):

‘That’ in your case is a pronoun which can replace the pronoun who.
[Generally](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/that) it is used as the subject or object of a relative clause, especialy one defining or restricting the antecedent, sometimes replaceable by who, whom, or which: the horse that he bought, the man that came, etc.

Comment: who and whom actually have specific use cases with which often native English speakers are not even familiar. for posterity, here are those rules: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whovwhom.asp

Comment: @Metagrapher Oh, I'm so sorry. I'm also answering/editing the similar question of who/whom. This was my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Metagrapher Yeah. It was this - http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18420/whom-did-she-invite-or-who-did-she-invite

Comment: @MaulikV Oh, you were asking the question? I shall provide an answer then :)